# iOS Xcode development builds, under which conditions the build deployed on device becomes invalid?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, development-environment, iphone-developer-program

I have a number of iOS devices on which I can deploy development builds of my apps, signed using iOS team provisioning profile. The devices are added to the development program via Xcode. I deploy apps to these devices via a cable connected to my Mac.

I've observed that some devices can no longer run the app after some - the app just closes immediately upon tapping the icon. Updating the device to a new version of iOS seemed to have fixed the issue.

This makes me ask -

**Under which conditions can a development build deployed on device stop working?**

- if I revoke/request a new iOS team provisioning profile?
- if I remove the device from a list of development devices for the Apple developer program?

I want to make sure that I can potentially hand a development build on a device to a person like a sales representative and would not have to try to track down the device again if somehow the build stops working/refuses to start again.

Answer (score 1):

If you deploy your app  to devices "via a cable connected to my Mac." it can't be invalidated by revoking provision or working with devices tab. In fact, your app don't even know what are you doing with your provisioning profiles. I think that the problem that occurred was not related to this.

Comment: That's good to know, I guess the advice to testers experiencing this would be to just reboot the device.